# It cost lots of time to save state on hdfs in flink

Tags: hdfs, apache-flink

For flink heap state, checkpoint to hdfs will cost lots of time or hang up when state achieves over 10G. From web dashboard, we can see most of the time is used in async period, maybe it is always waiting block writing on hdfs. Is there some way to solve the problem?

Comment: You can use `minPauseBetweenCheckpoints` and incremental checkpoints for large state checkpoints. Take a look the following link: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/large_state_tuning.html

Comment: yes, I have added the features, but it's still too slow.

Comment: Can you provide some more informations, before and after the changes ?